# how to control for loop

Tags: javascript

this is my code......initially alltextboxes is showing...if i click the next or prev button it works properly....but i want only two textboxes per each click so initialy should show two text box ..........how i get it........how to solve......

see for full code:http://jsfiddle.net/sankarss/gAVZ8/22/

```
function starts(values)
{

    maximum=values;
    var form = document.forms[0];
    var container = $("#sankar");
    container.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < maximum; i++)  
        container.append('<fieldset style="width: 250px; height: 80px;"><legend>Files of ' +(i + 1) + ' / ' + maximum + '</legend><input type="text" name="name' + i + '" /><br /><br /><input type="text" name="topic' + i + '" /></fieldset>');

    goto(form, 0);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to do anything in my browser.

Comment: What do you want to do is not clear from your question

Comment: hi..u see http://jsfiddle.net/sankarss/gAVZ8/22/

Answer (score 1):

Simply put this code under the `for()` line:

```
if(i>=2){
    continue;
}
```

Ad@m

Comment: @MVS800824 Try `break;` instead of `continue;`. Ad@m

Comment: this is correct or not.......     for (var i = 0; i < maximum; i++) 
 {
 if(i<=2){
      container.append('<fieldset style="width: 250px; height: 80px;"><legend>Files of ' +(i + 1) + ' / ' + maximum + '</legend><input type="text" name="name' + i + '" /><br /><br /><input type="text" name="topic' + i + '" /></fieldset>');
    }  
 goto(form, 0);
 break; 
 }